# Somewhat laggy (stutter) ViewPager when XML file contains imageviews

Tags: android, android-fragments, imageview, android-viewpager

I have a ViewPager that has a new Fragment for each page. I made a fragment to test out my ViewPager, this fragment has an layout that looks like this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:orientation="vertical">
<TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Large"
        android:text="@string/textView_ride_height_overview_heading"
        android:id="@+id/textView_ride_height_overview_heading"/>
<View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:background="#FFFF3BB2"
        android:id="@+id/view_ride_height_heading"/>
<ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollbars="none">
    <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">
        <ImageView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:background="@drawable/image_border"
                android:src="@drawable/ride_height_overview"
                android:contentDescription="@string/imageView_ride_height_overview_content_description"
                android:id="@+id/imageView_ride_height_overview"/>
        <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/imageView_ride_height_overview"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium"
                android:text="@string/textView_ride_height_overview_summary"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

I used three of the same fragments to test out the swiping function. The swiping isn't too bad but it is still relatively laggy compared to fragments that does not contain any imageviews. So I suspect that every move I make when I swipe is taking longer because the image needs to be redrawn on the screen, can this be the possible culprit?

This is my main screen handler, it contains a list view of the possible items you can navigate to.

```
public class MainScreenHandler extends Activity {

private ArrayList<SubScreenFragments> subScreenFragmentList = new ArrayList<SubScreenFragments>();

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_screen_handler_layout);

    subScreenFragmentList.add(new SubScreenFragments("Ride height", new FragmentRideHeightOverview(), new FragmentRideHeightOverview(),
            new FragmentRideHeightOverview(), null));
    subScreenFragmentList.add(new SubScreenFragments("Toe", new FragmentRideHeightOverview(), new FragmentRideHeightOverview(),
            new FragmentRideHeightOverview(), null));

    String[] listViewNameArray = new String[subScreenFragmentList.size()];
    for (int i = 0; i < listViewNameArray.length; i++) {
        listViewNameArray[i] = subScreenFragmentList.get(i).getListViewName();
    }
    ListView listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
    listview.setClickable(true);
    ArrayAdapter<String> listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.listview_row_layout, listViewNameArray);
    listview.setAdapter(listAdapter);
    listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), SubScreenHandler.class);
            Bundle myBundle = new Bundle();
            myBundle.putSerializable("fragmentList", subScreenFragmentList.get(i).getFragments());
            myIntent.putExtras(myBundle);
            startActivity(myIntent);
        }
    });
}
}

class SubScreenFragments {
    String listViewName;
    Fragment fragmentTab1, fragmentTab2, fragmentTab3, fragmentTab4;
public SubScreenFragments(String listViewName, Fragment fragmentTab1, Fragment fragmentTab2, Fragment fragmentTab3, Fragment fragmentTab4) {
    this.listViewName = listViewName;
    this.fragmentTab1 = fragmentTab1;
    this.fragmentTab2 = fragmentTab2;
    this.fragmentTab3 = fragmentTab3;
    this.fragmentTab4 = fragmentTab4;
}

public String getListViewName() {
    return listViewName;
}

public ArrayList<Fragment> getFragments() {
    ArrayList<Fragment> fragmentList = new ArrayList<Fragment>();
    if (fragmentTab1 != null)
        fragmentList.add(fragmentTab1);
    if (fragmentTab2 != null)
        fragmentList.add(fragmentTab2);
    if (fragmentTab3 != null)
        fragmentList.add(fragmentTab3);
    if (fragmentTab4 != null)
        fragmentList.add(fragmentTab4);
    return fragmentList;
 }
}
```

And my sub screen handler, that handles the fragment population of the viewpager.

```
public class SubScreenHandler extends FragmentActivity{
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.sub_screen_handler_layout);
    ArrayList<Fragment> fragmentList=new ArrayList<Fragment>();
    fragmentList.addAll((ArrayList<Fragment>) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("fragmentList"));
    for (Object item : fragmentList) {
        if (!(item instanceof Fragment)) {
            throw new ClassCastException("List contained non-Fragment objects: " + item.getClass().getCanonicalName());
        }
    }
    ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
    viewPager.setAdapter(new myPagerAdapter(getFragmentManager(), fragmentList));
    CirclePageIndicator circlePageIndicator = (CirclePageIndicator) findViewById(R.id.indicator);
    circlePageIndicator.setViewPager(viewPager);
}


class myPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    ArrayList <Fragment> fragmentList = new ArrayList<Fragment>();
public myPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, ArrayList<Fragment> fragments) {
    super(fm);
    fragmentList.addAll(fragments);
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int i) {
    return fragmentList.get(i);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return fragmentList.size(); //nothing implemented here yet...
}
}
```

NOTE:
I couldn't get the code to line up properly so ignore the bad format.

Comment: Does anybody have a solution for me?

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you find a solution?